# combine div:after with url link and hover selector

Tags: html, css, url, hover

Is it possible to combine the following div:after...

```
.homepage .tm-toolbar:after {
display: inline-block;
width: 196px;
height: 196px;
margin-top: -107px;
margin-left: 60px;
content: "";
background: url("../../../../../images/logo/logo_big.png"); no-repeat 0 0;
background-size: 100%;    
}
```

with the hover selector so that the picture gets changed?

And is there a way to set a link for the whole div/picture?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hover on which element? You can just use `.homepage:hover .tm-toolbar::after` or `.homepage .tm-toolbar::after:hover`. Note that for pseudo-elements you should use `::` instead of `:`. The latter is reserved for pseudo classes.

Comment: and wrap the div in href tag or use javascript

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I'm trying to get the hover on the after element.

I tried

.homepage .tm-toolbar::after:hover {
background: url("../../../../../images/logo/logo_small.png"); no-repeat 0 0;
}

but it doesnt work.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes: How can i wrap a "div:after" in a href tag?

Comment: you will need to add `.tm-toolbar` div in `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You just need this :

```
.homepage .tm-toolbar:hover:after{
    background: url("../../../../../images/logo/logo_big2.png"); no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100%;    
}
```

Here is a little fiddle showing this working : http://jsfiddle.net/etgm0v8g/

If it doesnt work on your page, the problem could be elsewhere.
Have you checked your selectors ?

Or maybe your image path ? (try absolute path)

Also, you can't set a link on pseudo elements. CSS should be only used for design, not content.

Comment: thank you @FC' , but that doesnt work for me.

I tried 

.homepage .tm-toolbar::after:hover { background: url("../../../../../images/logo/logo_big.png"); no-repeat 0 0; }

and...

.homepage .tm-toolbar::after:hover { background: url("../../../../../images/logo/logo_small.png"); no-repeat 0 0; }